# Snapshot of a part of a file in Vim: hide comments and blank lines

Tags: c++, c, vim, comments

How to temporary show a snapshot of a file, while hiding comments and blank line?

The purpose would be to get a catch of a C++ function (for example), in a dense page formating.

A manner to do that is to use the global command to filter out lines of comments

```
:g!/\/\/
```

but then the syntax highlighting and move controls disappear.

The folding feature of Vim is a way to do the job, but it does only reduce several consecutive comments to a single line that is visually intrusive.

Anyway, folding is still useful to hide long C-like comments, for example with:

```
:set foldmethod=marker
:set foldmarker=/*,*/
```

But I did not manage to easily fold both C (/*...*/) and C++ (//...) comments in a single command.

**The ideal trick would**:

- *hide* (not just *fold* in a single line) comments and blank lines,
- perhaps indicate hidden lines with a character on the first column,
- handle both C and C++ comments,
- while preserving the syntax highlighting,
- and, ideally, the ability to *browse* the code,
- permits an easy *revert* to come back to the "commented" view.

So as to transform the following code:

```
/** Let say hello
* and do not forget anybody
*/
void hello( int arg )
{
  // OMG an hello world!
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

} // where is the world?
```

Into the following buffer:

```
void hello( int arg )
{
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All comments can be removed from the source with the following command:
`:%s/\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/\n\{,1}\|^\s*\/\/.*\n\|\s*\/\/.*//`

This can then be undone with the `u` command, assuming no other actions are there to be undone.

Since vi regexes can be extremely cryptic, below is an explanation of each part.  The entire regex is split into three parts separated by an OR operator (`\|`).

`\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/\n\{,1}`
This is to match block comments of the form `/* ... */`.  It matches the string '/*' (`\/\*`) followed by zero or more of any character, including new line, but matching as few as possible (`\_.\{-}`), followed by zero or one newline (`\n\{,1}`).  The reason it matches zero or one new line is to handle both the case where there is code on the same line as the comment and the case when the comment is on a line by itself.

`^\s*\/\/.*\n`
This is to match comments of the form `//...` where the comment is on a line by itself.  It matches zero or more whitespace characters that start with the beginning of the line (`^\s*`) followed by the string '//' (`\/\/`), then zero or more of any character (`.*`), ending with a new line (`\n`).

`\s*\/\/.*`
This matches comments of the form `//...` where the comment follows code.  It matches any amount of whitespace (`\s*`) followed by the string `//` (`\/\/`) and then any number of characters that are not newline (`.*`).

This is the best I can come up with at the moment, if I can think of a way to hide instead of delete the comments, I'll update this post.

Update:
A possible way to simply "hide" the comments might be to color them the same as the background.  This would render them invisible.  However, I currently don't know how feasible that idea might be or how well it would generalize.  I don't know enough about colors in vim to be able to write a script to accomplish this.

Comment: Adding a way to delete empty lines in this single command would do a sufficiently good job. But something like adding a "|\s*\n" in the matching part does not seems to work, any idea?

Comment: @nojhan I've edited the command to remove the newlines, and tested it and it worked.  It does have the effect of removing all blank lines, I'll see if I can think of a way to only remove blank lines resulting from removing comments.

Comment: @nojhan I've updated the post again with a command that should work now.  It will remove the new lines resulting from removing comments, but leave all other blank lines.

Comment: Nice.  Question: any way to enhance this to eliminate "#if 0...#endif" as well? (as opposed to a second pass run w/ a 2nd regex)

Comment: @chaz8705: to clarify about the "#if 0" question above, no worries about nested #if directives or #if (...), just simple #if 0...(blah) #endif sections.  I already have something that eliminates these, but it would be great if your command above could be enhanced to handle them as well.

Comment: @Dan Simply tacking on your regex with the or operator should work.  It may require surrounding your current regex with parenthesis, depending on what is in it.  To summarize, adding `\|\\(Your regex here\\)` between the `*` and `//` at the end should do the trick.

Comment: @chaz8705: Ah yes, now I understand... and your example above also handles comments that span newlines (\_) so that should be all that I need.  Thanks for the help, this will come in handy with some of the legacy code I have to go through right now (sad that it reads better w/o the comments!)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If there is more than one block-style comment in a source file, it deletes everything in between the first and last one. Need to change it to this to work: `:%s/\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/\n\{,1}\|^\s*\/\/.*\n\|\s*\/\/.*//`

Comment: @histumness Thanks!  I've edited the command as suggested.  For anyone else wondering what the difference is, the `*` after `\_.` was changed to `\{-}`.  This changed the matching from greedy matching (match as many characters as possible) to lazy matching (match as few characters as possible).